# GA4: Geographic Data showing "(not set)" when event is sent using Measurement Protocol

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4, measurement-protocol

I send events through Measurement Protocol and I have no problem obtaining the data from the custom dimension′s parameters.

However, the data for "City" and "Country" are just displayed as "(not set)" for all the events I have sent until now.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I missed this information from the site.

> Geographic information is only available via
> automatic collection from gtag, Google Tag Manager, or Google
> Analytics for Firebase.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4

Comment: this is so important feature, hopefully GA4 measurement protocol will have it as soon as UA is permanently stop on July 2023